# Cfdump component method values, not component structure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have recently started using a cfc component to store user information in the Session variable. I used to store them as individual variables in Session, such as Session.UserId, Session.Firstname, or Session.Lastname. This new component nicely wraps that all up for me into a component with get methods for each value I need (i.e. Session.User.getUserId(), Session.User.GetName(), etc).

But when I do a cfdump of the session variable for debugging, it displays the object structure's metadata. I'd like to see the values returned by the component's get methods. Any way of using a cfdump to output the function values with the object metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any way of using a cfdump to output the function values with the object metadata?

Yes, use accessors.

```
<cfcomponent accessors="true">
    <cfproperty name="userID">
    <cfproperty name="firstName">
    <cfproperty name="lastName">
</cfcomponent>
```

Try to `<cfdump>` this object, you'll see the property values.

Answer (score 6):

`<cfdump>` isn't magic, all it does is output the value you give it. As your CFC instance doesn't expose any public properties reflecting these values, `<cfdump>` hasn't got any way of knowing what they are.

If you need to extract *all* the private properties reflecting your former session scope in one hit, then you need to create a method to do so, and then `<cfdump>` *that*.  EG:

```
public struct function getVariables(){
    return  variables;
}
```

If you are abstracting the values you want further, eg into `variables.sessionStuff` (`variables.sessionStuff.userId`, `variables.sessionStuff.name` etc), then write a method `getSessionStuff()` which returns `variables.sessionStuff`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Adobe continued support for this, but in ColdFusion 8 any variable within the `THIS` scope is automatically considered public (and thus visible in `cfdump`) while using `VARIABLES` scope explicitly is considered private (and thus invisible in `cfdump`). This way you can also avoid having stack overflows when you keep component references in your component (cfdump used to solve them recursively ending in an infinite loop). But then again: this was probably fixed in ColdFusion 9 and above.